# Find the count of elements in one matrix equal to another

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to compare the elements of two matrices and return a count of how many rows are exactly same. The ismember function returns one column for each column present in the matrix. But I want just one column indicating whether the row was same or not. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean compare _i_-th with _i_-th row, or _i_-th row with _j_-th row for all pairs of _i_, _j_?

Comment: @LuisMendo: Yes. Compare i-th row with i-th row. Both the matrices have same number of row.

Comment: See my answer then, first part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare **corresponding** rows of the two matrices, just use

```
result = all(A==B, 2);
```

Example:

```
>> A = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6]
A =
     1     2
     3     4
     5     6
>> B = [1 2; 3 0; 5 6]
B =
     1     2
     3     0
     5     6
>> result = all(A==B, 2)
result =
     1
     0
     1
```

---

If you want to compare **all pairs** of rows:

```
result = pdist2(A,B)==0;
```

Example:

```
>> A = [1 2; 3 4; 1 2]
A =
     1     2
     3     4
     1     2
>> B = [1 2; 3 0]
B =
     1     2
     3     0
>> result = pdist2(A,B)==0
result =
     1     0
     0     0
     1     0
```

Comment: The first part is what I needed. Thank you !